# What audio file formats does Android support?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, audio

What audio file formats does Android (ICS in particular) support? If this depends on the device, how can I find out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Supported Media Formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) page of the Android SDK documentation (under the "Core Media Formats" subsection) outlines all of the formats that vanilla Android supports. Audio codecs specifically noted are:

- AAC LC/LTP
- HE-ACCv1
- HE-ACCv2
- AMR-NB
- AMR-WB
- FLAC
- MP3
- MIDI
- Vorbis
- PCM/WAVE

As the documentation also notes, manufacturers can provided decoders for additional media formats, meaning that this *can* potentially vary by device a bit. I'm not aware of any simple way to determine which extra formats are supported by a device aside from simply copying a sample over and attempting to play it with the stock music player.

Similarly, specific apps can potentially provide software decoding for additional codecs. MX Player [provides codecs in the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.ffmpeg.v7_neon), for example.

Answer (score 0):

The [MOTODEV Site](http://developer.motorola.com/products) has the internal specs for every Motorola Android device. If you scroll to the "Media" section, you'll see the list of supported formats. Usually it's the Core Media Formats plus any extras.

For example, the RAZR...

http://developer.motorola.com/products/razr_maxx_xt910/